# Copying Email body using HTML

Tags: html, vba, outlook, html-email, office-automation

I am building some macros to automate daily MI which is currently a manual process. We receive stats into one of our mailboxes, the stats arrive on the body of an Email. I have created the below macro which almost does what I want to, however it pastes the text of the body of the Email into a single cell rather than retaining the formatting of the Email. I've read online I will need to use HTML however, I'm not that familiar with using HTML.  Could someone kindly please provide some pointers?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 Sub GetFromOutlook()

 Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim OutlookNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
 Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Dim OutlookMail As Variant
 Dim i As Integer

 Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
 Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.Folders("XXX").Folders("XXX").Folders("XXX").Folders("XXX")

 i = 1

 For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.Subject >= Range("Subj2").Value Then
      Range("DDump2").Value = OutlookMail.Body
      i = i + 1
     End If

Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: did you try: Range("DDump2").Value = OutlookMail.HTMLBody

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("DDump2").Value = OutlookMail.Body
```

The Body property returns a plain text string. Use the [MailItem.HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) instead. It returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately.

```
Range("DDump2").Value = OutlookMail.HTMLBody
```

Comment: Thanks for the response much appreciated! - Stupid me didn't realise the data in the email was in a table. I've managed to get it too work by changing/adding the following  in the middle of the if statement

Comment: If OutlookMail.Subject >= Range("Subj2").Value Then
           OutlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Tables(1).Range.Copy
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data2")
        .Range("a1").Select
        .PasteSpecial Format:="HTML"
        
        
     End With